# Xpath with htmlagilitypack

Tags: xpath, html-agility-pack

I am try to select the "string b" text node using XPath with the HtmlAgilliyPack.

```
<div>
  string a<br/>
  string b<br/>
  string c<br/>
</div>
```

I am not sure how to select the text?

This won't work `//div/text(1)`

Anybody has some suggestions?

Comment: You can't select string b using xpath.. Tell us little more about your problem.

Comment: @Loclip of course he can.

Comment: Even in different ways. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
//div/br[1]/following-sibling::text()[1]'
```

The direct following text after the first `br`.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with your expression:

- XPath starts counting at 1, so you want the second text node
- `text()` is a node filter which does not accept arguments. If you want to limit to the second text node, use the predicate `[position() = 2]` or the short version `[2]`.

Use this expression:

```
//div/text()[2]
```

Selecting text nodes can include some hassles, chopping leading and trailing whitespace and omitting whitespace-only text nodes is implementation-dependent.